# Best way to multithread a large number of short processes

Tags: java, multithreading

```
ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
//fill tasks with tasks to execute
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(processors);
for (Task t : tasks)
    executor.execute(t);
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    //wait for tasks to be completed
}
```

So this is the general code i'm working with at the moment. It works, but i'm not sure if it's the best/most efficient way to multithread for my use case. I did notice that the method above can cause BSOD, i'm not sure if that's something that this particular way of multithreading is causing, or if it's just an issue with my computer/mulithreading in general.

TLDR; what is the best way to multithread a large number of short tasks?

Comment: was just giving some pseudo code, fixed

Comment: Adding safeguards wouldn’t hurt, such as having no more than 50 threads running at a time..

Comment: Yes, i'll set the processors in the thread pool to a specific number that's less than the amount of core i have available

Comment: @numbtongue it's a newFixedThreadPool. so the thread numbers are limited.

Comment: Instead of looping to check if isTerminated using awaitTermination would be better.

Comment: If you get BSOD, it's unlikely to be a Java issue. Since the code will spike all CPU cores, it could actually be a heating issue, i.e. inadequate cooling.

Comment: May be memory overflow (due to boxing/unboxing in a loop?), or can you see event logs for what’s caused blue screen.. Interesting to see what happens on non Windows OS..

Comment: @Andreas i agree it seems unlikely it's the program. The only reason i say this is because i've checked my hardware out and the PC is fine under heavy load, it's only when i run the program (even only on 2/8 cores) it causes the issue

Comment: @numbtongue going to give it a try wit awaitTermination. I'm not sure if it matters but i also have to create a new Calculation object for each calculation. I don't know why that would differ from creating a list and populating it with tasks just thought i'd mention it